# Flutter: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I am currently having a problem with not having access to the `Navigator` in my Flutter app. This is the code:

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<LanguageBloc>(
          create: (_) => serviceLocator<LanguageBloc>(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<MaintenanceBloc>(
          create: (_) => serviceLocator<MaintenanceBloc>(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<VersionBloc>(
          create: (_) => serviceLocator<VersionBloc>(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<AuthBloc>(
          create: (_) => serviceLocator<AuthBloc>(),
        ),
      ],
      child: const _AppView(),
    );
  }
}

class _AppView extends StatefulWidget {
  const _AppView();

  @override
  State<_AppView> createState() => _AppViewState();
}

class _AppViewState extends State<_AppView> {
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  NavigatorState get _navigator => _navigatorKey.currentState!;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: _navigatorKey,
      title: AppConfig.appName,
      locale: context.select((LanguageBloc bloc) => bloc.state.language.toLocale()),
      supportedLocales: AppLanguage.toLocales(),
      localizationsDelegates: [
        AppLocalization.getDelegate(getAppTranslations: serviceLocator<GetAppTranslations>()),
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      theme: AppTheme.themeData,
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          settings: settings,
          builder: (context) {
            return const Placeholder(
              color: Colors.red,
            );
          },
        );
      },
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MultiBlocListener(
          listeners: [
            BlocListener<MaintenanceBloc, MaintenanceState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                switch (state.runtimeType) {
                  case InMaintenance:
                    _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const MaintenancePage()),
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                    break;
                  case NotInMaintenance:
                    break;
                }
              },
            ),
            BlocListener<VersionBloc, VersionState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                switch (state.runtimeType) {
                  case InitialVersionState:
                    break;
                  case CheckingVersion:
                    break;
                  case Outdated:
                    _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const OutdatedPage()),
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                    break;
                  case UpToDate:
                    break;
                }
              },
            ),
            BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                switch (state.status) {
                  case AuthStatus.authenticated:
                    _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()),
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                  case AuthStatus.unauthenticated:
                    _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginPage()),
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                  case AuthStatus.unknown:
                    _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginPage()),
                      (route) => false,
                    );
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

With my code I am pretty much following the code you see here in the [BLoC Login Tutorial](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterlogintutorial?id=app).

For whatever reason this results in `Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value` at `NavigatorState get _navigator => _navigatorKey.currentState!;` meaning that the `Navigator` cannot be accessed.

When I run the same code but without using the `_navigatorKey` and instead doing `Navigator.of(context)`, I get this error:

`Unhandled Exception: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.`

`The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a descendant of a Navigator widget.`

indicating again that I don't have access to the `Navigator`.

This is the point which confuses me, as the `MaterialApp` is a `parent` widget, so the `Navigator` should be accessible. Wrapping the `MultiBlocListener` in a `Builder` to get the latest `context` does not fix the issue. Not using the `context` provided by the seperate `BlocListener`s inside `MultiBlocListener` does not help either.

At this stage I have no idea what is wrong here, especially because I am following the tutorial linked above.

Comment: I'm thinking the API has changed since the tutorial was written. The key is in the documentation on the `builder` property for `MaterialApp` (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html#builder): "**A builder for inserting widgets above the Navigator**." Thus, all of your `BlocListener`s are being inserted *above* the `Navigator` in the tree, meaning they can never get any sort of reference to the `Navigator` from the `context`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it really helped me. I fixed the issue by providing the code with the `MultiBlocListener` as `home` to the `MaterialApp`.

Comment: Glad it helped! For completeness and to help others who may stumble across this page in the future, I've pasted my comment as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking the API has changed since the tutorial was written.

The key is in the documentation on the `builder` property for `MaterialApp` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp-class.html#builder

> **A builder for inserting widgets above the Navigator.**

Thus, all of your BlocListeners are being inserted above the Navigator in the tree, meaning they can never get any sort of reference to the Navigator from the context.